# How to createReadStream inside another createReadStream pipeline in nodeJs?

Tags: node.js, json, parsing, stream, xlsx

I'm trying to create a read stream with the createReadStream in nodeJs like this:

```
fs.createReadStream('/file')
    .pipe(parse())
    .on('data', async (row) => {
        await workOnData(row);
    }).on('end', () => {
        console.log('done processing main stream!')
    })
```

What the function workOnData is doing is simple.
It's another readable stream that reads a json chunk by chunk and do some work with the previous read stream row.

```
 function workOnData(row) {
    fs.createReadStream('/jsonfile.json')
    .pipe(parse())
    .on('data', async (jsonRow) => {
        //DO SOMETHING WITH THE ROW AND THE JSON ROW
        //LIKE SEARCHING ROW WORDS INSIDE JSON ROW
    })
    .on('end', () => {
        console.log('done comparing!')
    })
}
```

Is it possible to do something like that ? Or do you have better suggestions ?

If I can provide more details about the feature, I'm just parsing a xlsx file, and for each row of this file, I want to compare text inside this row, to another json file row, row by row. That's why I need to readableStream, do work tighly coupled on two different file.

The Json is a kind of dictionary and could be something like that

```
{
    "productName": [
        "description",
        "product",
        "name",
        "product name"
    ],
    "unit": [
        "unit",
        "bundle",
        "package",
        "packaging",
        "pack"
    ]
}
```

So for example, I am parsing the readable XLSX file, and on each row of it, I want to parse, always chunk by chunk, all the JSON file to find the right key according to words.
If the XLSX file is a row like

```
["description", "product name"]
```

I want to compare both row (JSON and XLSX) to get the key "productName".

Hope I'm clear, thank you very much !

Comment: so, parse() returns an instance of Duplex, workOnData is supposed to be a Promise, right? It is unclear what you're trying to do. Pipelines in node are really convenient and easy if you understand what you are doing

Comment: @AzizHakberdiev ty for your return :). What I want to do is simply find a way to stop the process at each row, to be able to do the work data thing. The workData is, first of all, another parsing stream by reading a json. I want to resume the first parsing stream only when the second with the json is done.

Comment: It is not necessary no stop the process, you can stop the stream using `stream.pause()`. I recomnend you to read the documentation for streams and and embark on this task with more advanced knowledge if you are currently learning node

Comment: @AzizHakberdiev What you suggest make sens, but I need to resume the first stream, when the second one is done. I could pass the first stream as a parameter to the second one but not sure if good practice. I already know the pause and resume thing but I wonder how to do it "outside" the main readable stream, in the second.